# Radical of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field. Suppose that $f\in F[X]$ can be written as $f=g^m$ for some separable polynomial $g\in F[X]$. Assume that $f$ has degree $\geq 1$ and $m\geq 1$. Define the quotient ring $A=F[X]/(f)$ and ${\rm Rad}(A)=\{a\in A \mid a^n=0 \hbox{ for some }n\in \mathbb N\}$.

**Question**: Why is ${\rm Rad}(A)$ generated by the class $g+(f)\in A$?

I see that the ring generated by the class $g+(f)$ is contained in ${\rm Rad}(A)$. But I'm not sure about the other direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're analyzing the structure of $A/(g^m)$, and we want to show that $(g +(g^m))= Rad(A/(g^m))$

Obviously $g+(g^m)$ is nilpotent in this ring, so $(g +(g^m))\subseteq Rad(A/(g^m))$.

To get the reverse containment, all we have to do is show that $Rad[(A/(g^m))/(g+(g^m))]=\{0\}$. By an isomorphism theorem, we can simplify this task to showing $Rad(A/(g))=\{0\}$

We'll employ the separability here. Since $g$ is separable, it is square free. If $q+(g)\neq 0+(g)$ and $q^2\in (g)$, then $q^2=ga$ for some polynomial $a$. Since $g$ is square-free, you can argue that $q$ divides $a$, and by cancelling we get $q=ga'$ where $a'$ is a divisor of $a$, but this is a contradiction to $q+(g)\neq 0+(g)$. This establishes that $A/(g)$ has no nonzero nilpotent elements, i.e. $Rad(A/(g))=\{0\}$.